# Check if array contains another array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have 2 arrays like so:

```
arr1 = [[1,2]]
arr2 = [1,2]
```

How do I check if arr2 is in arr1?
I have tried the following:

```
arr1.includes(arr2)
```

But this returns false. Is there an easy way to do this in JS?

EDIT: I would also like to get the true index of arr2 in arr1. For example:

```
arr1.indexOf(arr2) => 0
```

Because arr2 is the first index of arr1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple function that searches the list of arrays for `arr2`, keeping in mind that you need to `sort` before comparison. Here are some examples to get the `index` of `arr2` if it was found as well:

```js
let arr1 = [[1,2]];
let arr2 = [1,2];
console.log(arrayInList(arr1,arr2));
arr2 = [1,3]
console.log(arrayInList(arr1,arr2));
function arrayInList(arr1, arr2){
     if(!arr1 || arr1.length==0 || !arr2 || arr2.length==0)
          return false;
     arr2 = arr2.sort();
     let foundIndex = -1;
     for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
          let current = arr1[i].sort();
          if(current.length != arr2.length)
               continue;
          let areEqual = true;
          for(let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
               if(arr2[j] != current[j]){
                    areEqual = false;
                    break;
               }
          }
          if(!areEqual){
               continue;
          }else{
               foundIndex = i;
               break;
          }
     }
     return foundIndex;
}
```

A faster solution would be storing them in an object as follows:

```js
let arr1 = [[1,2]];
let arr2 = [1,2];
console.log(arrayInList(arr1,arr2));
arr2 = [1,3]
console.log(arrayInList(arr1,arr2));
function arrayInList(arr1, arr2){
     if(!arr1 || arr1.length==0 || !arr2 || arr2.length==0)
          return false;
     arr2 = arr2.sort();
     let set = {};
     for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
          set[arr1[i].sort()] = i;
     return (set[arr2]!=undefined)?set[arr2]:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the Array.isArray?

```
   let arr1 = [[1,2]];
   let arr2 = [1,2];
   for (let i = 0; arr1.length; i++) {
       if (Array.isArray(arr1[i])) {
         console.log("Found array!")
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
arr1 = [[1,2]]
arr2 = [1,2]
a = JSON.stringify(arr1);
b = JSON.stringify(arr2);
```

And check the value of the index, it will return -1 if arr2 is not inside arr1

```
a.indexOf(b);
```